# nextjs static website admin How to do router permission management

Tags: authentication, client, next.js13, app-router

How does the admin system manage user routing permissions and intercept redirects in nextjs13 app router mode, because it is deployed on a static page and cannot use middleware

Try to use HOC components to encapsulate an auth, but the level is not enough, want to see if there is no practice to do this scenario to learn